# List contents of a share on remote PC

Tags: powershell

I have a share on a XP machine which is NOT on our domain. I am trying to do some scripting with it by using PowrerShell remotely from our domain.

The issue is that I can't get the contents of it listed. I got error message while I was trying

```
New-PSDrive -Name "L" -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\10.10.13.5\d$\log"
```

> New-PSDrive : The specified drive root "\\10.10.13.5\d$\log" either does not exist, or it is not a folder.

And I don't see `Get-ChildItem` can work with `-Credential`.

Does PowerShell work with XP at all?

Comment: What’s the error

Comment: Can you ping to the machine? Did u try single quotes instead of double? Did you try to store root in a ‘$root’ ? Can you access the share by copy pasting that root path into explorer?

Comment: The remote computer is not on a domain, so you need to authenticate to it before you can access a share on it. (The `net use` command is useful here.)

Comment: I second what Bill said. The other computer could like be rejecting you since it will not accept domain credentials.... unless you do something silly with the everyone group..... Firewall could also be at play here.

Comment: `New-PSDrive` is not `Get-ChildItem` and *does* support passing credentials. You need to provide admin credentials, though, because you're accessing a folder through an administrative share (`D$`).

Comment: I was trying to mount this share in PS using `new-psdrive`, it didnt work. does not matter if I use `$` admin share or not.  I was using `get-childitem` in PS after using `net use` in cmd successfully. it did not work. I did try to use psexec to mount it under system account, did not work as well. Guess powershell just wont work with XP....

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the full `New-PSDrive` and `net use` commandlines you were using (you may obfuscate the actual credentials of course). The SYSTEM account does not have access to remote resources, so you can't use it for things like this. You MUST connect with a local user on the *remote* system. A local admin user if you want to connect to an administrative share.

Comment: Why is an XP online on any network anyways?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

net use z: \servername\folder /user:username password

If you can map the drive using this in CMD, implement it in PS

Comment: tried already, it only works in cmd, wont work in PS, same message:  either does not exist, or it is not a folder.

Answer (score -1):

To map a network drive in PowerShell you have to use the command like below.
make sure you encrypt username and password

```
$server = 'server1'
$username = '' # put username
$password = '' # put password
$sb ={
$remote_username = $args[0]
$remote_password = $args[1]
if ($(test-path y:\) -eq $false ){
    $net = new-object -ComObject WScript.Network
    $net.MapNetworkDrive("Y:", "\\10.10.13.5\d$", $false, $remote_username, $remote_password)
    }
if ($(test-path y:\) -eq $true){
    Get-ChildItem y:\ | Out-Host
    }

}          

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock $sb -ArgumentList $username,$password
```